# Install Sharepoint Desginer 2007 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, reports, windows-server-2008-r2

According to the [official Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2007](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21581) the system requirements don't support Windows Server 2008 R2

[image]

I need this software to generate a report on the site is being used (metadata). Have any of you tried this with success? What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

It is client products not the server. Why you want to install it on the windows Server 2008 R2.

Simply install it on your client machine and connect to the site & generate the reports.

Comment: Wait seriously? I assumed this had to have direct access to the database since it was grabbing information on site usage?

Comment: Crap, you need either Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP. Who has XP anymore?

Comment: It is client tool and all u need site collection url with site admin permission

Comment: What is ur is, I think it is fine for win 7 32bit or 64bit

Comment: Mine is Win 7 64 bit

Comment: I think it will be fine